# I Need help to deploy my asp.net website on server using VS-2013

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, html

I trying to deploy my website on my host server. It's showing it's successfully published. But when i am using my URL than it's giving me listed stuff,

> Index of /
>   Audio/
>   Contect.aspx
>   Default.aspx
>   and other my project file.

Why am not able to see my website. When i click `default.aspx` then i am able see just my webcode.

Help me out.

Comment: cloud you provide your web.config file code?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: emit your <httpRuntime targetFramewor="4.5.1" /> and add
<system.webServer>
     <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
          <clear/>
          <add value="Default.aspx" />
        </files>
     </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the IIS, that your folder is an **application**.

1. Open your IIS manager (might be at `Control Panel`, `Administrative Tools`, `Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager`)
2. unfold directory structure, until you find your application folder
3. right click, `convert to application`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should build you project web site and then make publish to you Windows server instance. (to *File system* or *FTP*). 
Details about publishing is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1y1404zt(v=vs.100).aspx

Then you will be able to configure IIS Web server to host your web site in the network, here is an example:

**Creating a site in IIS using GUI.**

---

**1.** Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).

**2.** In the Connections pane, right-click the Sites node in the tree, and then click Add Web Site.

**3.** In the Add Web Site dialog box, type a friendly name for your Web site in the Web site name box.

**4.** Click Select if you want to select a different application pool than the one listed in the Application Pool box. In the Select Application Pool dialog box, select an application pool from the Application Pool list and then click OK.

**5.** In the Physical path box, type the physical path of the Web site's folder, or click the browse button (...) to navigate the file system to find the folder.

**6.** If the physical path that you entered in step 5 is to a remote share, click Connect as to specify credentials that have permission to access the path. If you do not use specific credentials, select the Application user (pass-through authentication) option in the Connect As dialog box.

**7.** Select the protocol for the Web site from the Type list.
The default value in the IP address box is All Unassigned. If you must specify a static IP address for the Web site, type the IP address in the IP address box.

**8.** Type a port number in the Port text box.

**9.** Optionally, type a host header name for the Web site in the Host Header box.

**10.** If you do not have to make any changes to the site, and you want the Web site to be immediately available, select the Start Web site immediately check box.

Click OK.

*Keep in mind if you configured some host name and want to able you use it locally - you should add this host name to your windows Host file.*

**Example:**

mytesthost.local    127.0.0.1

Comment: @PavSraan You are welcome! If answer useful could you please mark it as "Useful". Thanks

Comment: few more questions please.

Comment: How to create online account for own website?
Which language do we need to use?
I already have form ready i don't how how to store user info. and where?

Comment: @PavSraan Guess you have to read http://asp.net tutorials :) It's very helpful for beginners. For example this is a article about configuring authentication/authorisation using ASP.NET Identity Framework http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project

Comment: @PavSraan If you think that answers are correct or helpful could you please rate it using UP Arrows on the left site or answer ;) It will help for another users to find correct answer.